# XPATH writing for HTML tag containg spaces before and after the text i.e. <button>spaces text spaces</button>?

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

### I am writing a selenium-java script and trying to assert the text "Export All", but because of spaces in-between the HTML tag, I am not able to assert it.

---

Can any one please help me write xpath for this?

- the parent element is a div
- The child element inside div tag are the button with a class locator and inside the button tag is a text say "Foo" but it contains a big space before and after the button tag i.e. button tag begins, spaces, text, spaces, button tag ends.

Comment: you can try the following xpath -- //div/button[contains(text(),'Foo')] or //div/button[contains(text(),'Foo') and @class='classname']

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your current xpath expression, but you can get rid of the spaces using normalize-space(.), example xpath:

```
normalize-space(//button/text())
```

Result: `Export All`

`normalize-space(.)` removes all leading and trailing spaces and replaces sequences of spaces with a single space.

And for completeness, to get the text inside the button inside a div with a specific `class="classname"`, following xpath:

```
normalize-space(//div[@class='classname']/button/text())
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space